# Is there an algorithm to extend the shortest path in a graph until it cannot be extended further?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to find the longest path in a graph this graph is created from grid.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6WEO.png)

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of how this should work? Pictures would help :)

Comment: Yes, I put a image in the description, I just want to extend the shortest path from snake head to the food position until no more

Comment: Would it work to just go up all the way, then one to the right, then down all the way, then one to the right ... until you reach the right edge of the map, then go back to the left edge. So probably leave a space for that at the top or the bottom :)